# Find highest and lowest number from the string of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that returns the highest and lowest number in a list.

```
def high_and_low(numbers):

    return max(numbers), min(numbers)

print(high_and_low("1 2 8 4 5"))
```

But I have this result:

```
('8', ' ')
```

Why do I have `' '` as a lowest number?

Comment: A space is lower than all the other characters. Maybe try a *list* of ints instead?

Comment: You're passing the numbers as a string, which is text, not numbers

Comment: Your argument is a string, not a list of numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve your desired result you can call `split()` on the string you are passing in. This essentially creates a `list()` of your input string—which you can call the `min()` and `max()` functions on.

```
def high_and_low(numbers: str):
    """
    Given a string of characters, ignore and split on
    the space ' ' character and return the min(), max()

    :param numbers: input str of characters
    :return: the minimum and maximum *character* values as a tuple
    """
    return max(numbers.split(' ')), min(numbers.split(' '))
```

As others have pointed out you can also pass in a **list** of values you'd like to compare and can call the **min** and **max** functions on that directly.

```
def high_and_low_of_list(numbers: list):
    """
    Given a list of values, return the max() and 
    min()

    :param numbers: a list of values to be compared
    :return: the min() and max() *integer* values within the list as a tuple
    """
    return min(numbers), max(numbers)
```

Your original functions does technically work, however, it is comparing numerical values for each **character** and not just the **integer** values.

Comment: It will find the `min` and `max` from the number as string, which will be lexicographical min/max. For example: "11" will be treated as smaller than "2". and performance wise, here you are splitting the string twice.

Answer (score 8):

You are passing string to a function. In order to achieve the desired result, you need to split the string  and then type-cast each element to `int`. Then only your `min` and `max` function will work expectedly. For example:

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    #    split numbers based on space     v
    numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers.split()]
    #           ^ type-cast each element to `int`
    return max(numbers), min(numbers)
```

Sample Run:

```
>>> high_and_low("1 2 8 4 5")
(8, 1)
```

Currently your code is finding the minimum and maximum value based on [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) of the characters.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this solution, it gave me the little detail I was missing. Can you please explain why the loop is in square brackets? Is it just to ensure the result will be in the form of a list?

Answer (score 1):

Another (faster) way using mapping:

```
def high_and_low(numbers: str):
    #split function below will use space (' ') as separator
    numbers = list(map(int,numbers.split()))
    return max(numbers),min(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string by `' '` and pass it as Array

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    # split string by space character
    numbers = numbers.split(" ")
    # convert string array to int, also making list from them
    numbers = list(map(int, numbers))
    return max(numbers), min(numbers)

print(high_and_low("1 2 10 4 5"))
```

Comment: That will still pass it as text, so `"1 10 2"` will output 2 as the highest number.

Comment: You are right ... we can fix that by mapping @ThomasWeller

Comment: This code fails on Python 3 with "ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence".

Comment: and there is another fix for this problem .... thank you @MarkDickinson

Answer (score 0):

use `numbers_list=[int(x) for x in numbers.split()]`  and use `numbers_list` in `min()` and `max()`.
`split()` turns `'1 23 4 5'` into `['1','23','4','5']`; and by using a list comprehension all the strings get converted to integers.

Comment: we can't use `split()` and nothing else ... there is mistake for numbers like 10

Comment: i had forgot that the values in the list are still strings, i edited my answer.