# Why Python max() does not return maximum value?

Tags: python-3.x

Just First week of learning Python I am trying to print max value from python 3 list. But output is not the max number.

Code:

```
amount = ['123250','546698','456987','8','1']
print(max(amount))
```

Output:

8

Screen shot:

[image: Code execution in VScode]

Comment: Strings are compared lexicographically. "8" is greatest in your list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find highest and lowest number from the string of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053227/find-highest-and-lowest-number-from-the-string-of-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using numbers as strings.
Convert your list to have only integers

```
amount = ['123250','546698','456987','8','1']
amount = [int(value) for value in amount]
print(max(amount))
```

This will output

```
546698
```

Answer (score 0):

declare the list as a list of ints, not strings ('' is used to wrap around str vars):

```
amount = [123250,546698,456987,8,1]
print(max(amount))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert list of string to list of int using map and use max method.

```
amount = ['123250','546698','456987','8','1']
print(max(map(int, amount)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list's elements are in string format. You should change it to integer. map() function helps to convert from string format to integer. That's why some functions such as max or sort functions don't work correctly until you convert elements into integer.

```
    amount = ['123250','546698','456987','8','1']
    amount=list(map(int,amount))
    print(max(amount))
```