# Need the largest negative number from a list in Python

Tags: python

The assignment is:

- Create an empty list called temperatures.
- Allow the user to input a series of temperatures along with a sentinel value. 
  (do not use a number for a sentinel value) which will stop the user input.
- Evaluate the temperature list to determine the largest and smallest temperature.
- Print the largest temperature.
- Print the smallest temperature.
- Print a message that tells the user how many temperatures are in the list.

The issue I am having is that if my list contains `[-11, -44, -77]` my program prints `-11` as the lowest temperature. But I need it to print `-77`.

My code:

```py
# Create a list called temperatures to capture user input
temperatures_list = []

# Create a while loop to capture user input into the temperatures_list<br />
if __name__ == "__main__":<br />
    while True:
        enter_number = (input("Please enter a temperature (enter stop to end): "))
        if enter_number == "stop": break
        temperatures_list.append(enter_number)
    lowest_temp = min(temperatures_list)
    highest_temp = max(temperatures_list)
    total_temps = len(temperatures_list)

    # Print output of temperatures input by user
    print(f"The numbers you input are:", temperatures_list)
    print(f"The lowest temperature you input is: ", lowest_temp)
    print(f"The highest temperature you input is: ", highest_temp)
    print(f"There are a total of {total_temps} temperatures in your list")
```

Comment: You need to convert the inputs to integers. You're comparing strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Python max() does not return maximum value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63820220/why-python-max-does-not-return-maximum-value) Same problem but with max instead of min

Comment: No, your list doesn't contain `[-11, -44, -77]`. See how to create a [mcve]. Challenge your assumptions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20449427/6045800)

Comment: @barmar, if I use INT, then my sentinel (stop) will not work and the program errors out

Comment: @peterWood my list is populated by the user input. I was simply providing an example when stating [-11, -44, -77]

Comment: @Trottd those are integers. `input` returns strings.

Comment: @Trottd do the conversion after the check for `stop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the numbers are in string format, so min() and max() aren't comparing the numerical values of the list values. This should do the trick:

```
# Create a list called temperatures to capture user input
temperatures_list = []

# Create a while loop to capture user input into the temperatures_list<br />
if __name__ == "__main__":<br />
    while True:
        enter_number = (input("Please enter a temperature (enter stop to end): "))
        if enter_number == "stop": break
        temperatures_list.append(int(enter_number))
    lowest_temp = min(temperatures_list)
    highest_temp = max(temperatures_list)
    total_temps = len(temperatures_list)

    # Print output of temperatures input by user
    print(f"The numbers you input are:", temperatures_list)
    print(f"The lowest temperature you input is: ", lowest_temp)
    print(f"The highest temperature you input is: ", highest_temp)
    print(f"There are a total of {total_temps} temperatures in your list")
```

As a side note, you could add in a try-except to catch cases where the user enters values that aren't a number, as this would cause your program to crash when converting the values to integer-type. For example:

```
# Create a list called temperatures to capture user input
temperatures_list = []

# Create a while loop to capture user input into the temperatures_list<br />
if __name__ == "__main__":<br />
    while True:
        enter_number = (input("Please enter a temperature (enter stop to end): "))
        if enter_number == "stop": break
        try:
            temperatures_list.append(int(enter_number))
        except ValueError:
            print('That wasn't a number! Try again)

    lowest_temp = min(temperatures_list)
    highest_temp = max(temperatures_list)
    total_temps = len(temperatures_list)

    # Print output of temperatures input by user
    print(f"The numbers you input are:", temperatures_list)
    print(f"The lowest temperature you input is: ", lowest_temp)
    print(f"The highest temperature you input is: ", highest_temp)
    print(f"There are a total of {total_temps} temperatures in your list")
```

float() would also work if you'd like to include numbers with decimals in.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the input to int before adding it to `temperatures_list`:

```
while True:
    enter_number = (input("Please enter a temperature (enter stop to end): "))
    if enter_number == "stop": break
    temperatures_list.append(int(enter_number))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function

```
def lowest_temp(temps):
    p = 0
    for i in temps:
        if i < i+1:
            p=i
    return p
```